# Error(s) not allowing import of Grails project to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, import, nullpointerexception

I am using

Eclipse: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)

Grails: Version 2.3.11

Java: Version "1.8.0_101"

I am trying to import an already exiting Grails project into Eclipse workspace using the import wizard and I see following error.

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.livexp.ui.GroupSection.(Lorg/springsource/ide/eclipse/commons/livexp/ui/WizardPageWithSections;Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/springsource/ide/eclipse/commons/livexp/ui/WizardPageSection;)V

If I try to force import the Grails project then I encounter a nullpointer exception. (Stack trace given below)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Bundle: org.eclipse.jface 3.12.0.v20160518-1929
Message:
Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.dispose(Wizard.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.hardClose(WizardDialog.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4553)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4143)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Import.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.run(CommandAction.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ImportResourcesAction.run(ImportResourcesAction.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4553)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

I related and tried to follow the the solution in this [page](https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE-1347) but it did not work.

Comment: I doubt this is a factor here but you can't use Java 8 with Grails 2.3.x. The first version of Groovy that worked with Java 8 was 2.3, so you need to use Grails 2.4+ to use Java 8. If you can't upgrade you can just use Java 7.

Comment: Burt did you mean to say. "The first version that worked with Java 8 was 2.4, so your need to use Grails 2.4+ to use Java 8."  I had trouble with Intellij using Java 8 and Grails 2.3.11.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Changing the JDK compiler level compliance to 1.7 (from 1.8) did not work for me.